# nested vector with polymorphic_allocator cannot be constructed via emplace_back

Tags: c++, allocator, emplace

The following code:

```cpp
std::pmr::vector<std::pmr::vector<int>> outer_vec(std::pmr::get_default_resource());
outer_vec.emplace_back(std::pmr::get_default_resource());
```

fails with quite inconceivable error message ending with

> static assertion failed: construction with an allocator must be possible if uses_allocator is true

The vector can clearly be constructed with an argument of `std::pmr::get_default_resource()`, such as:

```cpp
std::pmr::vector<std::pmr::vector<int>> outer_vec(std::pmr::get_default_resource());
std::pmr::vector<int> inner_vec(std::pmr::get_default_resource());
outer_vec.push_back(std::move(inner_vec));
```

And `std::pmr::vector` can use `emplace_back` to construct an element, such as:

```cpp
std::pmr::vector<std::vector<int>> outer_vec(std::pmr::get_default_resource());
outer_vec.emplace_back();
```

Why does the combination of both fails? What `static_assert` is failing?

Note that if the outer vector is not `pmr`, it works:

```cpp
std::vector<std::pmr::vector<int>> vec;

vec.emplace_back(std::pmr::get_default_resource());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator` uses *uses-allocator construction* if supported by the constructed type. `std::vector` does support *uses-allocator construction* and the allocator type of the inner `std::vector` is compatible with that of the outer one.

In consequence *uses-allocator construction* will be used by the outer vector. This means, whenever the vector constructs a new element it will automatically pass its own allocator as another argument to the constructor of the element. (Specifically `get_allocator()->resource()` is passed at the end of the argument list in this case.)

You are trying to pass an allocator manually to `emplace_back`, so that in effect with the above two allocators will be passed to the inner vector's construction, resulting in failure.

So, what you really want is just `outer_vec.emplace_back();`. It will propagate the outer vector's allocator to the inner vector.

Note that `outer_vec.push_back(std::move(inner_vec));` will do the same. It will also propagate the outer allocator to the new "move"-constructed inner vector, resulting in moving all elements to a new allocation if necessary. It won't use the original allocation of `inner_vec` if its allocator compares unequal to `outer_vec`'s allocator.